# How to avoid Memory Error

Tags: python, memory, plot, pytables

How should I proceed in order to be able to plot some data coming out from a big pytable (17GB).

If I try to store the values that I need, I get `Memory Error`, something like this:

```
for row in tab.iterrows():

    x.append(row['date'])
    y.append(row['temperature'])

    #this will not end, raises Memory Error
```

If I try to live update a plot with the data, without storing any values, I get this message:

```
MemoryError
QImage: out of memory, returning null image
```

So then? What should I do If I need to plot some data from such a big table?

Note:

Working with python 2.7 32 bits on a Windows 64-bit machine 8GB

I know that a solution would be to use python 64, but, it should be possible to handle in python 32 too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out what section of your data you *really* want to plot.  It doesn't make sense to have > 1 million dots on your screen.  You say it yourself: `... if I need to plot __some__ data from such a big table`.

I haven't worked with `PyTables` yet, but [the documentation](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html#table-methods-reading) says it's returning `numpy` objects, so no need to iterate over the rows.

```
histogram, xedges, yedges = 
   numpy.histogram2d(
      tab.col('date'),
      tab.col('temperature'),
      bins=50)

pyplot.imshow(heatmap)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, but, for this case in particular it makes sense to have many dots in the screen since I am interested in the density...and with `some data` I wanted to refer to some columns from the pytable, not all columns are of my interest, but thanks again!

Comment: Then you don't need all data either.  You can reduce the data set to NxM counter values, where NxM corresponds to your resolution.

Comment: that sounds interesting, but correct me if I am wrong:  reducing the data is exactly what I am doing when storing some data with `x.append` and `y.append` and as I said, it raises `memory error` before ending the for loop

Comment: No; you're copying it.  Reducing it can be done with e.g. `scipy.stats` or `numpy.histogram2d` or the like.

Comment: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/plotting_distributions.html#multivariate-density-estimation-with-kdeplot

Comment: ok then I definitelly don't know how to mix the pytables selection tools with numpy...that would be great if you could extend your answer and explain it for me and for someone else that will find it useful for sure :)